# facebook - List people who shared URL, using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get a list of users who shared a URL, using Graph API?

("Shared" as in share{'share_count'}.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. That would be a major privacy issue. No one should be allowed to know if i shared something, unless i authorized it.